# Get running process' stdin/stdout with node.js

Tags: node.js, process, stdio

I am starting a process from node with [child_process.spawn](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.1/api/child_processes.html#child_process.spawn) and handling process.stdout/stderr data events, and writing to stdin.

Now, my node application may crash or get stopped, when it is restarted I find the process by it's PID, and then I would like to attach again to the process' stdin/stderr/stdout.

The process in question could be any daemon-like program, so I do not have control over it's behaviour (I cannot set up the process to redirect it's stdio upon receiving a signal, for example).

I am thinking wrapping the process using screen, redirecting stdio to a FIFO file (but the customFds option is deprecated in node 6), but none of that seems as clean as process.stdin.on...

Comment: Have you achive your goal? I will delete this comment after all but I was loking for something like that you asked, so share the answer If you had any success!

Answer (score -1):

There might be an easier way, using `fuser` I have created a situation here, where node.js has spawned a process and died

```
xxx@ubuntu:~/node$ node index.js 
Server has started
Request for / received.
About to route a request for /
Request handler 'start' was called

/home/xxx/node/requestHandlers.js:27
response.write(body);
            ^
ReferenceError: body is not defined
at Object.start (/home/xxx/node/requestHandlers.js:27:17)
at route (/home/xxx/node/node/router.js:4:18)
at Server.onRequest (/home/xxx/node/node/server.js:9:3)
at Server.emit (events.js:70:17)
at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1478:12)
at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
at Socket.ondata (http.js:1374:22)
at TCP.onread (net.js:348:27)
```

If I run `fuser <directory from which node started` - example `fuser /opt/node`, I see the pids I created

```
xxxx@ubuntu:~$ fuser node
node:                16490c 16491
```

Just to be double sure - running `ps`, I can see the matching pids

```
xxxx@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep find | grep -v grep
xxxx     16490     1  0 17:39 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c find / -name 'moo'    
xxxx     16491 16490 21 17:39 pts/0    00:00:04 find / -name moo
```

I can run `fuser -k /opt/node` to kill and clean up the pids started from `/opt/node`. I personally use `fuser` regularly at work and home to clean up any leftover processes.

I have tested `fuser` on ubuntu and solaris.

**NOTE:** The only thing you need to be careful about is if there is an SSH session on that directory it will be nuked along with any other process started from that directory.