# Get separate process' stdout/stdin with Node.js

Tags: node.js, process, stdio

*This question is essentially the exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167039/get-running-process-stdin-stdout-with-node-js), but that is a 2+ year old question and hasn't been properly answered yet.*

How do I get the stdin/stdout of an existing running process that Node.js didn't spawn with child_process (or has spawned it with child_process, but let it run detached (and then stopped/crashed, and had to restart))?

Comment: This is going to be pretty platform specific.  Here's one solution for Linux, using a 3rd party program (reptyr) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047581/capture-stdin-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-comm

Comment: @Joe well, is there a way to do it that doesn't use 3rd party programs? That's what I'm looking for, after all.

Comment: Well, you can look at the code in there for ideas.  What you're describing is not that easy to do.  https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr   It depends on ptrace, which might not work for your purposes.

Comment: @Joe Well, I guess I might as well use reptyr for now. Thanks anyway.